# Can Warforged be targeted by the Clone spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, spell-components, warforged

The [*clone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone) spell's components include, among other things (*PHB*, p. 222):

> at least 1 cubic inch of flesh of the creature that is to be cloned

However, [warforged](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged) do not have flesh as other humanoids do (*E:RftLW*, p. 35; *WGtE*, p. 67):

> Warforged are made from wood and metal, [...]

And per the next paragraph:

> Root-like cords infused with alchemical fluids serve as their muscles, wrapped around a framework of steel, darkwood, or stone.

This alone would seem to imply they cannot be targeted by the *clone* spell.

However, in the paragraph after that, their description also states:

> Although they were manufactured, warforged are living humanoids. Resting, healing magic, and the Medicine skill all provide the same benefits to warforged that they do to other humanoids.

Would this list include the *clone* spell? I'm struggling to understand whether *clone* would be considered healing magic, and if an inch of the warforged's "flesh" would work here.

**Can warforged be targeted by the *clone* spell?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We say plenty of plants have “flesh,” even though it is wood or other materials. Seems to me that warforged should be accorded the same courtesy. Yes, *clone* should be able to target warforged “flesh.”

Aside from the targeting concern, nothing else about *clone* has any reason to bar it from cloning a warforged, and certainly the warforged itself goes to pains to impress upon the reader the fact that warforged are the same as other living creatures.

Comment: I've never heard that about plants, but also, this answer is correct. Eberron goes so far as to say, "warforged are living humanoids," so it stands to reason that they have flesh. Additionally, *clone* requires flesh **of the cloned creature** so it's not like you could just throw some steel, darkwood, and stone in a vat and call it a day.

Comment: @ChumpNicholson In fairness, with plants, you’re usually talking about softer parts, often the part of the fruit that you eat.

Comment: ERFTLW also includes this info about Warforged on page 35: "Warforged are formed from a blend of organic and inorganic materials. Root-like cords infused with alchemical fluids serve as their muscles, wrapped around a framework of steel, darkwood, or stone." Warforged contain some amount of organic matter which, given your entirely valid interpretation that "flesh" has a wider meaning than just "human skin/muscle," further supports this answer.